# как изменить мою нейронную сеть так, чтобы она могла распознавать любую картинку, а не только ту, название которой записано?

Tags: python, файлы

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np

model = VGG16(weights="imagenet")

img = image.load_img('3SSScAbpJXQ.jpg', target_size=(224, 224))

x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)

preds = model.predict(x)

name='gg.png'
img1 = decode_predictions(preds,top=1)[0]
print(img1)
```

Вот сама нейронка, но её проблема в том, что она может распознавать только картинку, название которой ты запишешь в строке

```
img = image.load_img('3SSScAbpJXQ.jpg', target_size=(224, 224))
```

как этого избежать и автоматизировать процесс, дабы программа сама понимала имя картинки? Сразу распишу, что программа уже распознаёт объекты, проблема не в этом, она просто не может обработать объект, если не знает его имени, например, gg.jpg и так далее, я же хочу, чтобы имя каждого загружаемого объекта определялось и забивалось автоматически, без моего вмешательства в код

Comment: Нейронная сеть работает не совсем так, как вы того ожидаете. Что бы она делала предикт и определяла название изображения - надо ее обучить на именно таких же объектах, причем с названиями. Иначе ничего не получится. Т.е. надо что бы нейросеть определяла виды птиц, например, значит вы должны всем этим видам сеть обучить. Как вариант - взять уже обученную сеть с теми объектами которые и будут встречаться у вас в фотографиях (картинках).

Comment: Но ведь это и так уже обученная сеть, я делал это ранее. И вы, кажется, не поняли, сеть уже понимает, что изображено на картинке, но чтобы она обработала эту картинку, нужно написать её название, ну например gg.jpg и так далее

Comment: Возможно я не правильно понял ваши проблемы, но имя распознаваемого файла можно узнать автоматически только если вы заведёте специально папку для того что бы все файлы из неё распознавались. Например папку  Test. И, в коде читаете список файлов (имён файлов) ну и по очереди запускаете предсказание сети - таким образом вручную в код вбивать их имена не придётся. Ну или уточните - что на самом деле вы хотите? Очень сложно разгадывать ребус вашей задачи. И сложность не в реализации, сложность понять ваши желания.

Comment: Теперь вы правильно поняли мой вопрос, мне нужно узнавать именно имя распознаваемого файла. Я сделал папку, получается дальше надо настроить программу так, чтобы всё сохранялось в неё автоматически(тогда как это сделать?)?

Comment: И да, я попробовал сделать это с папкой, но оно не позволяет мне записать результат проверки папки в качестве имени

Comment: эээммм..... не понял куда сохранять надо. Кто мешает сохранить например CSV файл где будут сопоставляться название файла и его предикт? Или как вам надо? Надо менять имя файла? Если имя файла - то либо меняйте его модуль os позволяет это сделать. Либо, создайте папку, например Result и туда сохраняйте файлы с измененным именем, взятым из предикта.

Comment: я извиняюсь за то, что я такой нуб и говорю, возможно, полную херню, но можете, пожалуйста, показать ваше решение на примере кода выше, где изображение это 3SSScAbpJXQ.jpg, но нужно, чтобы считывалось любое?

Comment: Может стоит сначала изучить программирование хоть немного, а потом уже браться за нейронки. То что вы хотите - делается в три шага, причем в элементарном цикле: 1. Чтение очередной картинки из директории, 2. Распознавание. 3. В случае удачи - запись названия прочитанного файла в список. По  окончанию цикла у вас просмотрены все файлы в директории и создан список файлов, содержащих интересующий вас объект. Все. Тривиально и просто.

Comment: Суть вопроса заключается в том чтобы поочерёдно читать все файлы из папки, вызывать функцию с именем файла в виде параметра и записывать результат, который вернёт функци. Уберите пожалуйста метки «нейронные сети» и «изображения» и добавьте метку «файлы»

Comment: Так в том и проблема, что когда я всё это выполняю, то при вставлении на место названия картинки переменной, содержащей ровно такое же название этой картинки, мне попросту выдаёт следующую ошибку expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list. И происходит это независимо от того, как бы я не шаманил с кодом, всё равно оно ни за что не воспринимает переменную

Comment: Из вопроса непонятно что именно вы хотите и как переименовать... Что вы хотите сделать с результатом который вернёт функция decode_predictions ?

Comment: Можете выложить на файлообменник ZIP файл с 3-5 картинками и привести в вопросе ссылку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

def get_files_folder(folder):
    res = []
    if os.path.exists(folder) and os.path.isdir(folder):
        files = os.listdir(folder)
        for fl in files:
            filenam = os.path.join(folder, fl)
            if not os.path.isdir(filenam):
                res.append(filenam)
    return res

# получаем список файлов папки:
infolder = "D:/Test" # здесь папка откуда вы берете файлы для предсказания
outfolder = "D:/Out" # здесь файлы куда вы складываете файлы (если это нужно) с измененными названиями полученными в предикте.
file_list = get_files_folder(infolder) 

for file in file_list:
    img = image.load_img(file, target_size=(224, 224))
    # ну и здесь далее делаем всё то, что нужно делать с этим файлом
    # получаем предикт, если предикт выдаёт класс - собственно используем его, если кодированый клас,
    # то сперва декодируем его например в переменную resname, то сохраняем так:
    # image.save(os.path.join(outfolder, resname + '.png'), "PNG")
```

В общем с файлами тут работа простая. Выше всё объяснено. Что не понятно - пишите.

Comment: По-моему эффективнее было бы читать картинки батчами по 20-50 штук, генерировать 4D тензор из батча и подавать его на вход сети

Comment: @MaxU мы не знаем сколько картинок надо распознавать - возможно только одну.

Comment: С одной картинкой автор вопроса уже справился ;)